# phpMyAdmin time formatting

Tags: time, phpmyadmin, formatting

So, I have, in phpMyAdmin tool, two columns with the data type of time. The time output of these columns is hh:mm:ss.miliseconds and I want the output in hh:mm:ss.

How I do this?

For example:the output is 12:30:00.0000000 and I want 12:30:00

Comment: What tool do you have?

Comment: @DionJakobs phpMyAdmin tool

Comment: why do you downvoted all my questions?

Comment: I don't. I've only asked a question.

Comment: Not you @DionJakobs but other people

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to structure (top tab).
2. Then select the desired column
3. Hit change
4. Then make Length/Values blank